# RESTful Interface - Adding child objects

Tags: c#, rest

I have a RESTful interface exposed that allows for adding `Category` and `SubCategory` types.

**Category**

```
public class Category : EntityBase<Category>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**SubCategory**

```
public class SubCategory : EntityBase<SubCategory>
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

My question is should I pass the `Category` object with it's associated children `SubCategories` and then figure out what children are new:

```
public void AddSubCategory(Category category)
{
    // Figure out what object on the SubCategories collection are new (no PK value?)?
}
```

or would an approach like so be better?:

```
public void AddSubCategory(int categoryId, SubCategory subCategory);
```

Comment: Could more then one SubCategory be without a PK in the first method which accepts a Category object?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Yes, you could have more than one, but also, I would be OK with limiting it to one, in that case the second approach seems better to me.

Comment: I would go with approach #2. For example if the endpoint to get one category is `/api/categories/1`, then to get a category's subcategories would be `/api/categories/1/subcategories`. To add a subcategory to category 1, you would make a POST request to `/api/categories/1/subcategories` with the single category that you are adding (which basically looks like your second approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is cleaner but may take you a bit longer to setup on the front end.  You can go right to pushing the subcategory into your db/store [although I recommend doing a check in your stored procedure or entity repository to prevent two subcategories of the same name].

With the first approach you will need to iterate through the entire list of subcategories and possibility do a database call on each one or do something messy like submit the entire list to a stored procedure and churn through it in there.

The second approach will scale much better as well.  Consider how much more data is being sent to the server and then being reprocessed as the list of subcategories grows.

Besides transferring redundant data and needing to potentially cause a lot of extra database calls, you are probably concerned with the style choice for those who will implement your API and I think developers would expect separate methods for adding, updating, deleting and would find submitting the entire list confusing.

Cheers

Comment: I like this answer.  If you go with option one, you could optimize it a bit passing in the sub categories as a table-valued parameter, described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think there is no obvious answer to this question, and it comes down to a matter of taste.

Personally, if what you wish to only add one object at a time, i would go with the second approach, since it would save you iterating over a list of subcategories, which will benefit the performance of your application. You never know how your application will scale and you might end up with a lot of categories to deal with.

What i would do is take the second approach, but since you already have a CategoryId inside your second method, i would just change the signature to be:

```
public void AddSubCategory(SubCategory subCategory);
```

And extract the category id from the subCategory.